# SIFT Taylor Expansion working out subpixel locations

Tags: sift, subpixel

I am trying to implement SIFT and am currently just trying to understand how it works before starting to implement it in MATLAB, i understand most of it except how to work out subpixel accuracy using Taylor Expansion:

[image]

Above is the equation from the original paper. I have a few question on how it is applied.

Are the derivatives worked out in each dimension seperatly and then the equation applied to x then y?

Are the first and second derivates applied along the sigma axis aswell?

I have tired looking at previous implementations but cannot seam to find where they do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In our case, D is a volumetric function with variables **x** = (x,y,s), where s is the scale in the octave.

**Question:** Are the derivatives worked out in each dimension seperatly and then the equation applied to x then y?

**Answer:** "Are the derivatives worked out in each dimension seperatly?" Yes, for the first derivative, we calculate the partial derivatives for x, y, and s separately. "the equation applied to x then y?", No, the result of the partial derivatives will be a vector of length 3, which we simply multiply it by the inverse Hessian (3 X 3 matrix) to calculate the subpixel position of **x**.

For the second derivative, we use the Hessian Matrix (3X3 Matrix in this case).

**Question:** Are the first and second derivates applied along the sigma axis aswell?

**Answer** Yes, because it represents an axis in the 3D space, where D is defined.

**Notes:**

- For mathematically elaborated explanation [see](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10403/sift-taylor-expansion)
- For code in C++ [see](http://robwhess.github.io/opensift/).
- In order to calculate the partial derivative in the discrete domain,
  we use the the  [finite differences](https://www.google.pt/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=derivative%20approximation%20by%20finite%20differences&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=PV9jVbPzMoKt8wferICIBA).

Comment: why do we find sub pixels in sift? Why can't we just work with extrema?