# How to apply taylor series expansion to an image in opencv?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, sift, taylor-series

For computer vision project, I am trying to implement [D.Lowe paper(SIFT)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3AVISI.0000029664.99615.94). I am stuck in translating this(check the ppt image) into code. Can you please tell me how to apply taylor series expansion into code(the formula is below). Do you know any functions in numpy I can use to calculate this `D(x)`? can you give an exmple code for D(x) in python.

[image: Taylor series expansion]

[Video Credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPcMS49V5hg&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Does this help? http://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/taylor-series-with-python-and-sympy.html

Comment: Or this: https://pythonhosted.org/algopy/examples/series_expansion.html

Comment: @pookie - the first link you mentioned are using for sin(x). I am still not sure how I can apply that here, since its `x = (x, y, sigma)`. Thanks for those links but its not helping much.

Comment: FYI - DOG `D` - is a matrix of numbers.

Comment: dimensions of `D`?  shape of `D` and shape of `x`?

Comment: Have you had a look at the "Related" list? This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532415/sift-taylor-expansion-working-out-subpixel-locations?rq=1 looks promising, doesn't it?

Comment: thanks @gboffi it is helping

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To understand better go through [SIFT Taylor Expansion working out subpixel locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532415/sift-taylor-expansion-working-out-subpixel-locations?rq=1), 
later find below c++ code which is real implementation of SIFT.

```
static void interp_step( IplImage*** dog_pyr, int octv, int intvl, int r, int c,
             double* xi, double* xr, double* xc )
{
  CvMat* dD, * H, * H_inv, X;
  double x[3] = { 0 };

  dD = deriv_3D( dog_pyr, octv, intvl, r, c );
  H = hessian_3D( dog_pyr, octv, intvl, r, c );
  H_inv = cvCreateMat( 3, 3, CV_64FC1 );
  cvInvert( H, H_inv, CV_SVD );
  cvInitMatHeader( &X, 3, 1, CV_64FC1, x, CV_AUTOSTEP );
  cvGEMM( H_inv, dD, -1, NULL, 0, &X, 0 );

  cvReleaseMat( &dD );
  cvReleaseMat( &H );
  cvReleaseMat( &H_inv );

  *xi = x[2];
  *xr = x[1];
  *xc = x[0];
}


static CvMat* hessian_3D( IplImage*** dog_pyr, int octv, int intvl, int r,
              int c )
{
  CvMat* H;
  double v, dxx, dyy, dss, dxy, dxs, dys;

  v = pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r, c );
  dxx = ( pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r, c+1 ) + 
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r, c-1 ) - 2 * v );
  dyy = ( pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r+1, c ) +
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r-1, c ) - 2 * v );
  dss = ( pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl+1], r, c ) +
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl-1], r, c ) - 2 * v );
  dxy = ( pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r+1, c+1 ) -
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r+1, c-1 ) -
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r-1, c+1 ) +
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl], r-1, c-1 ) ) / 4.0;
  dxs = ( pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl+1], r, c+1 ) -
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl+1], r, c-1 ) -
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl-1], r, c+1 ) +
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl-1], r, c-1 ) ) / 4.0;
  dys = ( pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl+1], r+1, c ) -
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl+1], r-1, c ) -
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl-1], r+1, c ) +
      pixval32f( dog_pyr[octv][intvl-1], r-1, c ) ) / 4.0;

  H = cvCreateMat( 3, 3, CV_64FC1 );
  cvmSet( H, 0, 0, dxx );
  cvmSet( H, 0, 1, dxy );
  cvmSet( H, 0, 2, dxs );
  cvmSet( H, 1, 0, dxy );
  cvmSet( H, 1, 1, dyy );
  cvmSet( H, 1, 2, dys );
  cvmSet( H, 2, 0, dxs );
  cvmSet( H, 2, 1, dys );
  cvmSet( H, 2, 2, dss );

  return H;
}
```

reference:
https://github.com/robwhess/opensift/blob/master/src/sift.c